# Interpreting = in aymptotic notation

Tags: asymptotics

We can interpret $f(n) + o(f(n)) = \Theta(f(n))$ as for any $g(n) \in o(f(n))$ there exists some $h(n) \in \Theta(f(n))$ such that $f(n) + g(n) = h(n)$. But can we perceive it as for any $g(n) \in \Theta(f(n))$ there exists some $h(n) \in o(f(n))$ such that $f(n) + h(n) = g(n)$? If yes how do you prove this second relation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider $f(n)=n $. Obviously, $2n \in \Theta(n)$, but $2n$ is not element of set $n+o(n)$, because $2n -n =n \notin o(n)$.

On other hand: $g \in f + o(f) \Rightarrow g=f+ \phi = f+ f \varepsilon$, where $\varepsilon \to 0$ , so, in non negative case, we can have, for example, $f \leqslant g \leqslant 2f$. So, $f + o(f) \subset \Theta(f)$.